# Why unboxing of method call parameters does not lead to a helpful NullPointerException

Tags: java

I investigated helpful NullPointerExceptions from Java 14 and tested different scenarios. Surprisingly, unboxing seems to lead to helfpul NPEs in some scenarios, whereas other scenarios do not contain any error message:

```
// NPE with message 'Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "index" is null'
Integer index = null;
int i = index;

// NPE with message null
List.of('a', 'b', 'c').indexOf(index);
```

I wonder, why the second example does not lead to the same message as the first one. I read JEP 358 and learned that the message is comuputed based on the byte code instructions. Are they different for these two scenrios? I expected both snearios to call Integer.intValue() to unbox the value.

(Tested with Oracle JDK 17.0.4.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is because the cause is different. The `List` created by `List.of` doesn't allow nulls, and when `indexOf` receives a `null`, it simply throws a `NullPointerException` without a message:

```java
@Override
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (!allowNulls && o == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    Object[] es = elements;
    for (int i = 0; i < es.length; i++) {
        if (Objects.equals(o, es[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

(from the `java.util.ImmutableCollections.ListN` class)

On the other hand, in the case of `int i = index;` it is compiled to the equivalent of `int i = index.intValue();`, and the JVM generates the message of the `NullPointerException` based on the method calls and variables involved.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel isn't this code supposed to be updated as to throw an exception with such specific message? ex `throw new NullPointerException("index parameter is not allowed to be null");`

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos That is a question you should ask of OpenJDK developers.